# PermissionError using testrunner of soapui through RobotFramework

Tags: web-services, robotframework, soapui

I'm currently working on web services test automation, to do it, I'm calling SoapUI testrunner.bat from robotframework to send a request using *run process* keyword. The command used:

```
run process  "AbsolutePath/testrunner.bat" -e"enpointURL"  -t"aboslutePath/soap-projectSettings.xml" -s"testsuitename" -c"testcasename" -r"aboslutePath/soap-project.xml"
```

The command, used in a cmd without admin permissions is working fine and making the request. If it's used from robot returns a *PermissionError: [WinError 5] Acces is denied*.

I've already checked the permissions of the SoapUI root folder (where testrunner.bat is) and the SoapUI project. All of them are "Full control" for my user.

Also, I've checked if there is any way to run process with admin permissions but nothing.

I'm not understanding something or missing something and I'm stucked.

Thanks in advance, best regards!

Comment: try to create a bat file in the same folder as the robot script and put that command inside and execute the single bat.
It could be even that the command is being sent incomplete as robot doesn't like huge keyword lines as apparently you will have here.

Answer (score 0):

okay, my fault.

I should use a tab instead a simple space

```
run process   "AbsolutePath/testrunner.bat"   -e"enpointURL"    -t"aboslutePath/soap-projectSettings.xml"  -s"testsuitename"  -c"testcasename"   -r"aboslutePath/soap-project.xml"
```

each argument of the command is also an argument in robot. I thought that all the command was an argument.